# What is the difference between "everything we studied before/earlier" and "everything we have studied before/earlier"?

Tags: present-perfect, adverbs, past-simple

Tell me please if there is any difference in meaning between the following sentences.

> In this class we are going to review everything **we studied before**.
>
> In this class we are going to review everything **we** **have studied before**.
>
> In this class we are going to review everything **we** **studied earlier**.
>
> In this class we are going to review everything **we have studied earlier**.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have titles like "Correct verb tense for XXX" rather than all options in it?

Comment: Actually I would like to know the difference

Comment: Because I am sure all sentences are correct, but I cannot see the difference.

Comment: There's no significant difference between *earlier* and *before*. However, using **Past Simple** or **Present Perfect** in your examples depends on a context.  If you imply a definite time in the past then you use **Past Simple**, if not but just say in general then **Present Perfect**.

Answer (score 2):

There is no significant difference in meaning between the four sentences. *Before* = on a previous occasion; *earlier* = at an earlier time (which might be earlier this week, this term or this year!)

The choice of tense (*studied* or *have studied*) is not significant in this context either.

Comment: Could you please clarify why `In this class we are going to review everything we studied earlier.` is correct? *Earlier* doesn't relate to any specific time and it also connects the past with the present so **Present Perfect** sounds like a better option here.

Comment: It's as acceptable as any of your other versions. _Earlier_ just means 'at a time before now'. You are welcome to use the present perfect if that seems better to you.

Comment: In that case, *earlier* must refer to a specific time in the past implicitly understood by the teacher and students (I assume it's a teacher talking to his/her class). So, there must be a proper context for using **Past Simple** with *earlier/before*.

Answer (score 2):

The present perfect is used when the speaker has in mind or wishes to signal that the finished action or state occurred in some timeframe that has no terminal time boundary in relation to a main time period (now/time of speaking/in this class). The earlier/previous studying occurred in some timeframe (the semester/term of the course) which has not yet terminated, at least in some sense—or it’s not considered or not seen as important to specify.

We have studied it [e.g., earlier in the course/before this class in the course, with the course continuing at the time of speaking].

The past simple is used when the speaker has in mind or wishes to communicate that a finished event or state occurred in some timeframe which finished in the past—or it’s not considered or not seen as important to specify.

We studied it [in past classes, which have ended].

The “past simple-exact time” idea is only a sort of rule of thumb: a specific/precise time is sometimes specified, but this is not a reliable rule. It quickly breaks down under scrutiny: I was born in France. (No time or specific/exact time was specified, yet we must stretch to find narrow contexts in which the present perfect would be used here.)

The “connection to the present” notion likewise often makes little or no sense. *I was born in France” certainly has a connection to the present. I’m alive now. Any past thing we mention now has a connection ton the present: We’re mentioning it in the present!

American speakers of English more often interchange the two tenses, while British speakers of English face more strict pressures to make a choice and convey it via aspect.

Earlier and before have the same meaning in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Well , Im going to explain grammatically

When we use *simple past* we should mention an **Exact time or priod** not an **unknown time** ... **But**

> In Every-Day English we **Sometimes** use it for **unknown** times

Therefore when a teacher says *We're going to review what we studied* , He probably means "What we studied in the last 
Sessions"

In the second sentence "**... We have studied before**"
Teacher Means "What we have studied in the last few sessions"

Third : "**... We studied earlier**"

> Teacher starts explaining a new subject then goes to subject 2 and then 3 .. in the last 10 minutes he/she says **We're going to review what we studied earlier..**

All of this happend in **One Session**

Number Four means exacty like Number 2

Though These explanations were based grammatical principles

> In every-day english we dont have to obey rules therefore dont get confused and dont be a Detail-oriented , **Most of fhe time** we use things which are grammatically **Incorrect** but others will always *Get the point*

Comment: You are being over-prescriptive. Both _before_ and _earlier_  mean simply _at a time previous to the present_. The teacher might mean 'earlier in this lesson' , 'earlier this week' or 'earlier this term'. Also, it's nonsense to say that 'when we use simple past we should mention an exact time'. There is no such rule.

Comment: Kate Bunting: Could you try to explain the difference for me.

Comment: @KateBunting - Well put; you should turn it into an answer.

Comment: As i said i explained "grammatically" @KateBunting , i hope you agree english cambridge https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/past-simple-or-present-perfect and https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-use-before-earlier

Comment: @KateBunting It's true that saying *when we use simple past we should mention an exact time*  is wrong. However, when we use **Past Simple**, we either specify an exact time in the past or imply some  specific time in the past.

Comment: Yes - as I mentioned in my original comment, the teacher implies 'the time when we previously looked at this topic'.